# How can I ensure an argument is a class field (Java)?

Tags: java, enums, arguments

I am creating an API that returns a list of Cars. The API user must be able to request that the list be filtered and sorted by a certain attribute (field) of the `Cars` class. How can I do that?

```
class Car {
  public final String model;
  public final String color;

  public Car(String m, String c) {
    model = m;
    color = c;
  }
}

class CarListRequest {
  public final String sortBy;
  public final String filterBy;
  public final List<String> filterList;

  public CarListRequest(String s, String f, List<String> list) {
    sortBy = s;
    filterBy = f;
    filterList = list;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to restrict, using Java language features, that sortBy and filterBy Strings cannot contain any other values than attributes (fields) of the Car class?

I know that I could use an enum to declare all attributes of Car however, that causes a duplication of Strings which I would like to avoid.

Comment: what's the duplication of strings? can you explain clearly?

Comment: If I create an enum, I'd have repeat 'model', 'color' etc in another place.  If the Car gets a new attribute, I have to edit two places. (Car class and CarAttributesEnum)

Comment: @greppz You should accept an answer. Doing so shows that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@hmc_jake 's reflection suggestion is quite valid. However, if you want to avoid reflection, you could do it using a class hierarchy:

```
class CarAttribute {
    private String attrib;
    public CarAttribute(String att){
        attrib = att;
    }
    // add getters and/or setters for attrib ... 
}

class CarModel extends CarAttribute {
}

class CarColor extends CarAttribute {
}

class Car {
    public final CarModel model;
    public final CarColor color;

    public Car(CarModel m, CarColor c) {
        model = m;
        color = c;
    }
}

class CarListRequest {
    public final CarAttribute sortBy;
    public final CarAttribute filterBy;
    public final List<CarAttribute> filterList;

    public CarListRequest(CarAttribute s, CarAttribute f, List<CarAttribute> list) {
        sortBy = s;
        filterBy = f;
        filterList = list;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection in Java, it is possible to inspect a class's fields.

When, for example, `s` is passed in, you can perform a check on the argument like so:

```
for (Field field : Car.class.getFields()) {
    if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
        Do something here to signal that s
        was a valid Field of the Car class.
    }
}
```

Doing this allows you to reflectively inspect the Car class in order to verify that the argument passed in is in-fact a field of that class.

Note, however, that if possible you should go with the enum or class hierarchy as reflection might be a little bit overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Much better to go with an enum than with reflection. Anyways, this seems to suit what the OP has asked for.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I agree with you. I added a suggestion to my answer.